# Can tgtadm serve up FC targets on Emulex/Qlogic HBAs?

Tags: fibre-channel

I'm trying to discern if 'tgtadm' can be used with mode 'fc'.  All the documentation out there tends to point to iSCSI only, though some spots hint at Qlogic FC HBA target mode integration.  Would love to avoid having to rebuild the kernel with SCST to do it properly, but I am guessing that is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

FCoE software target driver for Ethernet NICs (in progress) and Qlogic qla2xxx FC target driver (in progress) says https://github.com/fujita/tgt

Answer (score 0):

Download qlogic target mode driver from [git.qlogic.com](http://git.qlogic.com),it will solve your problem without need of compiling kernel. Also give try for [LIO](http://linux-iscsi.org/wiki/Main_Page).